# Тот кто дует?

Tags: значение-слов

Как назвать человека, который дует, скажем, в парус. Выдувальщик? Выдуватель? Дувач? Как-то иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словарях отмечаются два существительных  со значением лица, образованных от глагола «дуть»: выдувальщик стекла и надуватель (обманщик).

Остальные формы можно только придумать, используя авторскую  фантазию, например «надувальщик/надувщик /надувник  шаров».

Answer (score 2):

Я бы такого человека назвал  **ветродувом**. Учитывая что ветер от дыхания в парус был порывистым, просится еще слово **вдуватель**.

Comment: Вдуватель скорее от вдуть, вдувать.

Comment: Ветродув - лучший из предложенных вариантов, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 0):

А разве человек может дуть в парус? Это же не мыслимо.

Comment: Человек может дуть в парус, например, игрушечного корабля.

Comment: Дуть человек может во что угодно, в том числе и на парус. Смысла особого в этом нет.